# Inventory System Data Design Issue

Tags: database-design

So I have been trying to design a inventory management system for a Car Showroom. The problem with this design is that I can get a purchase but on selling the product I can't link it to my purchase. The idea I've came with up is add a **Batch_ID** to my **Inventory_Details** table but I can only link that **Batch_ID** in my details table not in my inventory table. Any suggestions will be helpful.

[image: Inventory System Design]

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. If you want a solution that exploits specific DBMS features, then please only add one tag for that DBMS

Comment: why sale and purchase ids are related to the same field of inventory?

Comment: Because I can easily join my sale or purchase with inventory table to find all my purchases or sales

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the forum! I would have "stock_sold" and "stock_to_hand" (i.e. inventory) in different tables. When a purchase is made, the car goes into the inventory table and when one is sold it goes into the stock_sold table... you could have a BOOLEAN (exact name will depend on RDBMS) is_sold field in inventory and just have one inventory table  to simplify?

Comment: The problem with a flag `is_sold` will be I need to track my sale and purchase independently of each other because of my `inventory_details`. e.g If a car is bought from the Vendor we say our purchase `inventory_details` `file` column is set to `received` but when the item is sold  `inventory_details` `file` column is set to `not received`.  With this the details should show on purchase the file was received and otherwise sold the customer didn't received it. @Vérace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a traditional **Inventory Warehouse System** or **Warehouse Management System (WMS)** whenever a new Item is put on hand (i.e. created or purchased, and therefore added to Stock) a unique identifier must be created, usually a **serial number**, **before** you can enter it into Inventory and adjust your quantity on hand. In the context of a Car Showroom, I would imagine this would the be the `VIN` instead. (I'm not an expert on cars but I believe that's a unique identifier.)

Even when an item is received in batch quantities, that many unique identifiers need to be added to your Inventory before you can add the quantity to your quantity on hand. Therefore if your `Purchase` table has a one-to-many relationship with how many cars a `Purchase` can buy, because of batches, then you can't directly relate it to your `Inventory` table (*yet*). Rather you should have a separate table such as `PurchaseLines` which is many-to-one with your `Purchase` table, and has a row with the unique `VIN` for each car that was purchased. (This is even a simplification, as a real **WMS** actually **normalizes** this further into at least 2 more tables for ledger purposes, but I think that's outside the scope here, and this should be sufficient to what you need.) Your `InventoryDetails` table would then contain the `VIN` as well and directly relate back to the `PurchaseLine` it came from.

Additionally you should have just an `Items` table that defines the criteria of your cars, so you can generically refer to your quantity on hand by `Item`. As I'm sure you don't want to track the individual quantity of a `VIN` which will always be 1 (since my changes above will result in that). Instead if you have an `Items` table with fields like `Model`, `Description`, `Color`, `MFYear`, etc then your `InventoryDetails` table becomes more **normalized** and only stores an `ItemId` field instead (one-to-one with the `Items` table). Then your `Inventory` table can now track quantity for an `ItemId` instead which would be the relationship between `InventoryDetails`.

Finally, the concept of an `ItemId` becomes universal throughout the **Warehouse Management System**. It is like your core unit of measure. It should be part of your Purchases (in `PurchaseLines`) and your Sales (in an equivalent `SalesLines` table as well), and is a way to establish what item was transacted on.

---

**Additional Resources:**

1. [Example ER Diagram of an Inventory Management System](https://mysql.tutorials24x7.com/blog/guide-to-design-database-for-inventory-management-system-in-mysql)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122490/discussion-on-answer-by-j-d-inventory-system-data-design-issue).

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider relating purchases and sales `car_id`s ?

Why not relate `car_ids` together? A `car_id` relates a purchase with a sale uniquely.

So in case, that car is sold you can relate it directly to the corresponding purchase that was done before.

Comment: You trying to say replace `ps_id` with `car_ids`? The problem with this is if I do that, consider if  purchase multiple car's and want to check the cars purchases as batch wise, I will not be able to distinguish which car is from which batch.